# Queue Name Type to use

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-7

I'm new in using Websphere MQ. I need help in this.

I have a websphere located in a server remotely and I have an application that retrieves and sends the information to the websphere. Is it possible to send my queue to a remote websphere server and at the same time retrieve it? It's something like this.
[image]

If yes, how should I configure this one in the websphere remote server? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say your question is confusing. You don't send/receive queue. You send/receive messages to queue or topic. Can you clarify?

**Update:**

You can have WebSphere MQ queue manager running on machine and client application on different machine. Application can send and receive messages to/from remote queue manager. This is called as the `client` mode connection to queue manager and most commonly used type of connection mode.

Please read the WebSphere MQ [InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp).

Comment: Actually, you're correct. My mistake. So is it possible to send my message between two different servers?